# Using Openpyxl to hide the columns

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
    
wb = Workbook()
sheet = wb.active
    
data = [
    ['Item', 'Colour'],
    ['pen', 'brown'],
    ['book', 'black'],
    ['plate', 'white'],
    ['chair', 'brown'],
    ['coin', 'gold'],
    ['bed', 'brown'],
    ['notebook', 'white'],
]
    
for r in data:
    sheet.append(r)
    
ws.column_dimensions.group('Item','Colour', hidden=True)
wb.save('filtered.xlsx')
```

When I try to hide columns for the Excel sheet, I got this error:

> "Item is not a valid column name"

Is there any way to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try referring to the columns by their column letters (`A`, `B`, etc.), like this:

```
sheet.column_dimensions.group('A', 'B', hidden=True)
```

(you were trying to call `ws.column_dimensions.group()` but it appears you meant `sheet.column_dimensions.group()`)